# How to increment in python-maya?

Tags: python, maya

dddSay, for example, that we have two lists that contain pointPosition info:

```
a = [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]
b = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
```

I'm gonna make a linear curve that has info of respectively list a and b:

```
cmds.curve(p = [('%d'%a[0][0],'%d'%a[0][1],'%d'%a[0][2]),('%d'%b[0][0],'%d'%b[0][1],'%D'%b[0][2])])
```

Imagine I have two lists. Each contains 100 lists. How can I increment '%d'%a[0][0] and so forth or it has another method?

Comment: it should be `%d` rather then `%D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to string format the values.

```
points = ( (0,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,2,0), (0,3,0) ) # ... etc.  
cmds.curve(p = points, d = 1)
```

If you need to intermingle the points, do it before you pass the point list in:

```
a = ( (0,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,2,0) ) 
b = ( (1,0,1), (1,0, 2), (1,0,3))
c = [] 
for idx in range (0, 3):
    c.append(a[idx])
    c.append(b[idx])
cmds.curve(p = c, d= 1)
```

Comment: it makes one curve. i don't need one curve

Comment: @iran then you should spend some more time asking precisely what you want to achieve. Because based on what you have asked, this answer seems correct.

Comment: Stylistically, this would be much better with zip and flatten, or a roundrobin generator.

Comment: I didn't want to confuse him something less explicit.